# How to Validate Multiple screen using selenium with eclilpse?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium. I am validating two screens, Login and Password screens using selenium.
The First screen is Login. If the username is correct then it will move to next screen that is Password.
But in the Password screen the driver not putting the password into the input box, nothing is happening. It stops at Password screen. Any solution for that ? my code is below.
It is working for Login screen.

```
  package Second;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

  public class Second {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Installed 
   Application\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://gamaa.ui.in/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("test");
        driver.findElement(By.className("mat-primary")).click();
       
        driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("1234");
        driver.findElement(By.className("mat-primary")).click();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is taking time to load the next page element use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for
`elementToBeClickable()`

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("password"))).sendKeys("jaipur");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your progress and steps using the next page after passing (login page) so you can validate with the page title or element on the page with explicitly wait method

```
String actualTitle =driver.getTitle();
String expectedTitle="Next Page Title";
if(actualTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedTitle))
System.out.println("Title Matched");
else
System.out.println("Title didn't match");
```

Or

```
Assert.assertEquals("Condition true", actualTitle, expectedTitle);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you may also use element_to_be_selected instead of element_to_be_clicked